# Restrict INSERT and UPDATE on a particular column to a user role

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a table that I'd like to prevent ordinary users inserting data into, while keeping the ability for certain user roles.

for update I can do this with:

```
DENY UPDATE ON table (col) TO "user";
```

However this doesn't work with INSERT:

```
DENY INSERT ON table (col) TO "user";
```

Error:

> Sub-entity lists (such as column or security expressions) cannot be
> specified for entity-level permissions.

Is there an equivalent method to achieve the same functionality with INSERT?

It seems that INSERT would always insert against all columns, is there a way to restrict inserts on this particular column to be NULL for certain user groups?

Comment: You *can't* stop someone from `INSERT`ing into a column because it doesn't actually make sense to. When you `INSERT` a row then a value is added to *every* column; if you stopped someone `INSERT`ing a value into a specific column then they wouldn't be able to `INSERT` a row.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965532/how-to-deny-insert-permission-to-all-users-sql-server

Comment: Perhaps a trigger on insert that would delete column for specific user?

Comment: The "simple" `VIEW` solution is likely what you are after; you can then give the `USER`(s) permission to `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` on the `VIEW` and the `VIEW` doesn't expose the column(s) you don't want them to be able to affect.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, this is the best approach, I wasn't aware you could insert into a view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on  my comment, I would use a "simple" `VIEW` that only exposes the columns you want the `USER` to be able to affect.

```sql
--Create sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY,
                            SomeDate date NOT NULL,
                            SomeInt int NOT NULL,
                            SomeString varchar(10) NULL);
GO
--Sample user
CREATE USER YourUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
--Create VIEW with SoemString missing
CREATE VIEW dbo.SomeView AS
    SELECT ID,
           SomeDate,
           SomeInt
    FROM dbo.SomeTable;
GO
--Give permissions on the VIEW
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON dbo.SomeView TO YourUser;
GO
--Testing
EXECUTE AS USER = 'YourUser';
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeDate, SomeInt)
VALUES(GETDATE(),12); --Fails
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeDate, SomeInt, SomeString)
VALUES(GETDATE(),4, 'abc'); --Fails
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeView (SomeDate, SomeInt)
VALUES(GETDATE(),15) --Success
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeView (SomeDate, SomeInt, SomeString)
VALUES(GETDATE(),19, 'abc'); --Fails, as column doesn't exist
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeView;
GO
REVERT;
GO
--Cleanup
DROP USER YourUser;
DROP VIEW dbo.SomeView;
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

If the `USER` does, for some reason, need access to see the data in the `TABLE`, you could also `GRANT` them `SELECT` on the table. Note that they don't require *any* permissions on `dbo.SomeTable` in the above solution, as they both have the same owner permission chaining occurs.